# Godaddy Email setup on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have purchased Domain and Email with Godaddy.
Someone helped me to host my domain on AWS successfully.

I have to setup EMAIL.
I have details of TXT records, CNAME Records, MX Records, SRV records details from Godaddy.

How do i add these details on AWS, so that i will receive email?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add each of these records via the the console.

Access your public hosted zone in the console.

For each record you have add it via the `Create Record Set` button.

If the domain is a subdomain then specify the subdomain value in the Name field. Select the type from the drop (CNAME, MX etc). Then in the value specify the value of your record

Steps to add these records (from the public hosted zone):

**For CNAME record**

- Click "Create Record Set"
- For `Name` value enter `email`
- For `Type` select `CNAME - Canonical Name`
- For `Value` enter `email.secureserver.net`
- Click `Create`

**For MX record**

- Click "Create Record Set"
- For `Name` value blank
- For `Type` select `MX - Mail exchange`
- For `Value` enter `0 smtp.secureserver.net`
- Hit return and on the next line enter `10 mailstore1.secureserver.net`
- Click `Create`

**For SRV record**

- Click "Create Record Set"
- Leave `Name` value blank
- For `Type` select `SRV - Service locator`
- For `Value` enter `100 1 443 autodiscover.secureserver.net`
- Click `Create`

**For TXT record**

- Click "Create Record Set"
- Leave `Name` value blank
- For `Type` select `TXT - Text`
- For `Value` enter `"v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all –"` including the `"`.
- Click `Create`

More information available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html).

Comment: I've clicked on create record set and after that how to proceed?

Comment: You should have a popup onthe right side of the screen. If the domain is a subdomain then specify the subdomain value in the Name field. Select the type from the drop (CNAME, MX etc). Then in the value specify the value of your record :)

Comment: Did you manage to add your records @ArunKumar? :)

Comment: From Godaddy: Set the following TXT records.
Name TXT Value
@ D5782239
@ v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all

CNAME Records: Find where to add a CNAME record and enter:
Host Points to
email email.secureserver.net

MX Records: Find where to add an MX record and enter:
Host Priority Target
@ 0 smtp.secureserver.net
@ 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net

SRV Records: Find where to add an SRV record and enter:
Port Protocol Name Service Priority Weight Target
443 _tcp @ _autodiscover 100 1 autodiscover.secureserver.net

Comment: Once i clicked on "Create Record Set", i see the below option in AWS : Name, Type, Alias, TTL, Value, Routing Policy. How do i add above values from Godaddy in AWS?

Comment: Hi @ArunKumar could you add these formatted to your question. I will then add to my answer the steps for each domain :)

Comment: I need to add these values from GoDaddy to AWS "Create Record Set". What should I add in each of the fields in Record Set? I have TXT, CNAME, MX, SRV values from GoDaddy. How do I add these values in AWS?

Comment: I understand, can you copy the records and put them in your question. Then I can update my answer for each record :)

Comment: Set the following TXT records. Name TXT Value @ D5782239 @ v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all

Comment: CNAME Records: Find where to add a CNAME record and enter: Host Points to email email.secureserver.net

Comment: MX Records: Find where to add an MX record and enter: Host Priority Target @ 0 smtp.secureserver.net @ 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net

Comment: SRV Records: Find where to add an SRV record and enter: Port Protocol Name Service Priority Weight Target 443 _tcp @ _autodiscover 100 1 autodiscover.secureserver.net

Comment: Updated answer @ArunKumar, this should provide you a step by step :)

Comment: Almost done. For CNAME, name field should be "email" word or the Email ID that I have registered with GoDaddy?

Comment: It should be whatever the subdomain is for the record (I assumed it was email). If you're not sure run https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#ANY/ on your domain and find the subdomain of the cname for your host :)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! I received the mail. Thanks again mate

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! I received the mail. Thanks again mate

Comment: Big help thanks.  Godaddy specifies a name but keeping the name blank on MX, TXT and SRV was the change I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a feature called "Amazon Lightsail" to start with, go thru this link https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/amazon-lightsail-partners-with-godaddy-to-simplify-wordpress-management/

Comment: I'm not a Tech guy sorry. I don't know how to do.